# How do I reference a textarea value in another table cell?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to reference the content of a text area, but I keep getting undefined:

```
$(".send-comment").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).siblings(".comment-text").val();
    alert(data);
});

<tr>
    <td>#textAreaTag(label=false, name="comment[text]", class="comment-text")#</td>
    <td>#submitTag(value="Send", class="send-comment")#</td>
</tr>
```

I suspect it might be because the send button has no siblings (it's alone in a td)... but surely, there has to be a better way to get the value than using this.parent().sibling().child()...

I'm using classes because I have several comment forms on the same page that belong to different posts.

FYI, the generated source from my framework is as expected...

Comment: Check the generated source...

Comment: @Felix Kling, I did, and it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".send-comment").click(function(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();     
    var prevCell = $(this).parent().prev();
    var data = $(".comment-text", prevCell).val();     
    alert(data); 
});
```

Alternate:

```
$(".send-comment").click(function(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();     
    var data = $(".comment-text", $(this).closest("tr")).val();     
    alert(data); 
});
```

Comment: brilliant, that works. Thanks. Is there a better way to do this? This looks like a disaster if the markup changed. The method will assume multiple posts and multiple comment forms.

Comment: @Mohamad: Have added an alternative, this works even if number of cells per row and their position changes....When you say change in the markup... what kind of changes are you anticipating...

Comment: let's say someone decided to stop using tables and switched to divs, for example. I was thiking of using unique ids on the fields instead!..

Comment: In that case you can use has selector along with the closest tag..like...$(".comment-text", $(this).closest(":has(.comment-text)"))

Answer (score 1):

The text area is not a sibling of the submit button (according to your code). The submit button's parent's (parent td) sibling's (td) child is submit tag.

so your code should be:

```
var data = $(this).parent().prev().find(".comment-text").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.comment-text')` for example